# Joining the Mile High Club (MHC) - Can I get into trouble?

Tags: air-travel, legal, sex

The same friend I already mentioned in [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3625/693), has an additional travel question. Recently, he read a lot about the Mile High Club (MHC). Wikipedia defines the mile high club as people who had sex on an air travel vehicle during a flight. Ideally it should be above 1 nautical mile (1852 meters). Could I get into trouble if I do this on a regular plane? For example, can I get arrested? Or banned from flying with this airline? Or flying at all?

Comment: As a mile is only ~1600m I suggest the easiest way is to find a really tall hill and book a night in a hotel there.

Comment: @Stuart: interestingly, I just found that there is no country in the world that lies entirely above that height (closest is Lesotho at 1400m).

Comment: Sure, but any hotel in La Paz, Bolivia will easily do the trick :)

Comment: Is your next post going to be *"How do I surf the Internet for porn while traveling, in a way that keeps me out of a Bolivian jail?"* Oh, wait... How does *your friend...*

Comment: @Joel Spolsky I don't understand the close vote. The question is neither ambiguous, nor vague or incomplete. And as I just found out by myself, there are clear answers to this question. There are special charter flights offered by companies just for the purpose to get into the High Mile Club.

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain my close at the time, which I should have. I closed this as "not a real question" because it's not an actual question somebody actually has. Stack works best when it's used to get the answers to questions people are actually facing, not for chit-chatty conversation.

Comment: I still don't like it that you just claim that no one can actually have this question. I've edited it a little bit too include more information to prove that it is an actual question of my friend.

Comment: @JoelSpolsky [I don't understand your explanation. I asked on meta.](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/631/why-was-the-mile-high-club-question-closed)

Comment: Re-opened as per discussion on http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/q/631/108

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee Thanks. And just in time I finally found the answer to my question.

Comment: Here's [one potential way not to get into trouble](https://www.facebook.com/TrimbleProductions/videos/873379386033152/).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just found an interesting article in the [local newspaper](http://www.blick.ch/erotik/bei-dieser-airline-rumpelts-nicht-nur-wegen-der-luftloecher-id1770801.html).

> CINCINNATI (USA) - Champagner, Schokolade und totale Diskretion: Das
>   bekommt, wer bei Flamingo Air den «Mile High Special» – sprich das
>   «Sex im Flugzeug»-Arrangement – bucht.

Unfortunately the article is in German, but the headline says more or less:

> Champagne, chocolate, and total confidentiality: This is what Flamingo
>   Air offers as their Mile High Special, i.e. whoever will book the "Sex
>   on Board of a Plane" arrangement will get this.

So there seems really to be a company that offers such services. And obviously I don't think I will get into trouble if using such a dedicated service.

Their story seems to be true. A quick Google search revealed that other newspapers in English are also reporting about this company. And even on the website of Flamingo Air, this service is mentioned. Funnily, there it is called [Romantic Flight](http://www.flamingoair.net/mile-high-club-romantic-flights).

Answer (score 22):

[Singapore Airlines](http://www.singaporeair.com/en_UK/flying-with-us/suites/) (and I think others) first class offers "compartments" similar to those found on sleeper trains, meaning there is a door you can close (and probably lock as well).  The compartment contains at least 2 seats, both of which recline completely into beds.

Comment: Nice suggestions. I just found this about this topic: "In November 2007, the BBC reported a story headlined "Airline Bans A380 Mile-High Club" about a measure taken by Singapore Airlines. The airline asked their first class passengers shortly after the introduction of their new Airbus A380 to respect the other passengers. The twelve first class cabins have double beds, but are not soundproof."

Comment: Many times the headline in a news story does not accurately reflect the content (the headline and article are almost always written by different people).  The airline statement does not mention any kind of ban.  I would interpret it just as an admonishment to keep quiet.  In practical terms, as long as they don't get complaints from other passengers, I don't see them having any ability or motivation to enforce what goes on.

Comment: I wouldn't risk doing it when flying *into* Singapore, though. They have an “Outrage of Modesty” law that can land you in jail if you offend the modesty of another person (*e.g.*, another passenger on the plane). ["Singapore enforces strict laws pertaining to the propriety of behavior between people and the modesty of individuals. ... Penalties may include imprisonment for up to two years, a fine, caning, or a combination thereof."](http://travel.state.gov/travel/cis_pa_tw/cis/cis_1017.html#criminal_penalties)

Comment: The Singapore Airlines "Suites" are not fully enclosed rooms, but more akin to low office cubicles.  Any tall person walking by can still see inside.

Comment: Interesting information, but it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Sexual use of these compartments is apparently also [banned by Singapore airlines](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/business/7071620.stm).

Comment: I've been in the Suites - not nearly private enough.

Answer (score 7):

My answer is: "it's depends on whether you bother anyone".

I know some friends who tried it during a night flight on a second class plane from Europe to an Indian Ocean island.  But they were silent, they made some gymnastics to achieve it under the carpet, and they had no immediate neighbour.

But I am sure that there are countries where it's not secure to do it unless you want to visit jail.

Comment: and many if not most airlines will ban you for life as a passenger for it.

Comment: "under the carpet"? I'm not familiar with this phrase.

Comment: I guess he means under a blanket :-)

Comment: under the... Those must have been some gymnastics.

Answer (score 6):

The wikipedia page [on the subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mile_high_club) doesn't offer a lot of detail, but does provide some clues to the answer to your question.

In short, engaging in sexual activities in front of other passengers is going to be illegal in most jurisdictions, and against airline policies in practically all cases.

Engaging in sexual activity aboard a plane in private, such as in the lavatory, is more of a legal grey-area. In the UK, for example, [sexual activity in a public lavatory may still be punishable as "public sex"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mile_high_club#Legality) although this has apparently never been tested in court.

In an episode of [1000 Ways to Die](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1105711/?ref_=ttep_ep_tt) in which a couple were killed together in the lavatory when the plane hit turbulence while they were fooling around, a flight attendant for an un-named (English-speaking, probably North-American) airline was interviewed, who said that customers are allowed to enter the lavatories in pairs, as long as they don't disturb other passengers. She seemed to imply it was a common practice, seen almost as "cute" by flight attendants. But I have no idea how authoritative this is, or even if she was a real flight attendant, or reading a script.

My advice:  If you're going to do it, only do it in the lavatory, and be very discrete and quiet, so as not to draw attention or offend others.

Comment: I used to work with a  woman who did this a few times. No idea if it was strictly allowed, but the flight attendants either didn't notice or didn't care. This was in the US.