# How to avoid toddlers on a long-distance plane flight?

Tags: air-travel, tips-and-tricks, children, sleeping, long-haul

I have recently taken a London - San Francisco (12 hour) flight, with a toddler in the seat directly behind me. His parents actively encouraged the kid to speak out in that typical proto-speech, while reading out from books. For 12 hours.

One might think that the industrial-strength earplugs I always carry with me would have helped. One would be very, very wrong.

What specific steps can I take in all of my future flights so that this experience will never, ever repeat itself?

Comment: Pretty remarkable that a toddler could read out loud non-stop for 12 hours!

Comment: Parents supplied the reading. Toddler repeat-screamed it.

Comment: Take an overnight flight.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: There are no overnight flights on that route.  Westbound transatlantic flights are almost always during daylight,

Comment: Earplugs are often designed to allow you to hear people talking while blocking machinery noises.  So they are not much good against children's voices.

Comment: Noise cancelling headphones are great for cancelling out engine noise but are no good for voices

Comment: I have noise cancelling earphones that excellently drown out my office mates' chatter, at least while playing music on a low volume. So, yes, there are those that work.

Comment: Just be thankful that the parents were engaged with their child and doing their best to minimize it's impact on you. You could have had a toddler screaming for 12 hours and constantly kicking the back of your seat, with the parents indifferent to their little darling's actions or even worse actively encouraging it.

Comment: @GregHewgill question on how to do that: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3677/joining-the-mile-high-club-mhc-can-i-get-into-trouble

Comment: @Peregrine Were you on my flight in January? I understand that kids will be kids but it pissed me off when the parents stay back and did nothing.

Comment: Be thankful the kid was being entertained and educated rather than being allowed to run around screaming, kicking the back of your chair etc.

Comment: Did you consider politely addressing the issue with the parents? Start with complements on their child's abilities and that it's good that they're encouraging him to read. Then mention that the child does seem to be participating at a rather high volume and ask if they would mind finding a quieter activity for the child for 30-60 minutes, just to give everyone in the area (ie, _I'm_ not the only jerk) a bit of a break. Some people, will, of course, get angry with you, but most will oblige.

Comment: I don't know if this applies for all flight companies, but with the ones I have experience, don't allow toddlers to be seated at the emergency exits and 1 below/in front of that row. So, if you can sit the emergency exit row, you should be fine.

Comment: Consider yourself lucky. When my son took his first flight, he got scared and yelled for 2 hours straight. I wish I could make him stop by reading, and I bet people around me wished the same.

Comment: @Luaan I agree that western childcare is environmentally unfriendly. Regarding 'more': it depends on the quantity: one child vs. one flight: probably. But for n flights a year, there is a n where your statement becomes false. But even if so, that does not counter my suggestion that planes are to be avoided due to their negative impact. As should any behavior strongly negatively impacting our environment, like wasting tons of diapers, etc.

Comment: I'll admit that the situation would probably disturb me, too.  On the other hand, I've flown a lot, and the percentage of times a child (or anyone else) irritated me is too small to justify spending time trying to avoid it.

Comment: Years ago, I was on a flight with two women sitting behind me. The 20 minutes before takeoff, I thought my head would explode, high voices, insipid dialogue. Right after takeoff, I listened for a crying baby. I walk back, and told the guy sitting there, who I could tell wasn't the dad, that I'd be happy to switch with him. He bolted for my seat. I told the mom I'll take her crying baby over the 2 women any day. I told her I had one of my own, and I was happy to sit with them.

Comment: You could wait until last to board a plane.  If there are toddlers on  board , give up your seat top a standby passenger and wait until the next one.  Repeat as necessary.

Answer (score 241, accepted):

To avoid disturbance from small children, you can use a multi-pronged approach:

- first, try to choose flights that are more of a hassle for parents. Generally this means night flights - some parents may be sure their child will sleep (and not bother you) but others are worried the child will not sleep and will cry. So they take a daytime flight and are willing to entertain them for the length of the flight
- second, try to minimize the impact of the child on you. Buy a more expensive ticket - first, business, even economy plus. Children are of course allowed in the more expensive zones, but they are in substantially fewer numbers. In some cases these children are experienced and quiet flyers, accompanying parents who have been kept awake by other people's children in the past. And do what you can to improve things at whatever seat you have. Bring noise cancelling headphones in addition to earplugs, for example. Bring some sort of music you can play that will drown out the repetitive reading.
- third, try to react in the moment in some way that is more positive than sitting in your seat seething. Go for a walk. Strike up a conversation elsewhere on the plane. Turn around and interact with the child, such as playing peek a boo over the back of your seat. It's probably likely to be quieter than the reading and even endear you to the parents. Tell the child your name and ask theirs, and smile. If in a few hours you want to ask the parents if there's a quieter form of entertainment available, you won't be the grumpy gus in the next row, you'll be the toddler's airplane friend.
- fourth, try to be realistic. No toddler does **anything** for 12 hours. They nap, they eat and drink, and so on. Focusing on the behavior that irritates you, to the extent you genuinely recall that it took the entire flight time, leaves you with a bad cloud around you that can take days to shake. When the noise starts, tell yourself it won't last the whole flight. Do something positive, listen to something, take yourself away from the noise. When the noise stops, be grateful, even if it's just a short respite.

And finally, when you leave the plane, be grateful that you are now done with that child and don't have to hear the noise or put in any effort to try to prevent bedlam. The parents will still be on duty for hours more today, and for another few decades in general. Count your blessings!

Comment: All good suggestions. I get on a flight thinking how I can stop being disturbed by other people, not how I can stop other people disturbing me.

Comment: Certainly "non stop" is hard to define, but I remember a ~9 hours night flight when my oldest daughter was just 18 months, and besides the occasional eat and nappy change breaks, she *was* non stop babbling and climbing out of and into the bed again for 8h, even from my perspective. The poor chap in the seat left to us had it worse, cause left of him was a single mother with an even younger child. We asked crew if he could be relocated, but there was nothing free. So for the grateful part you mentioned, one should be to not be in his place. It can always be worse

Comment: I would be extremely careful with trying to interact with the child. You do not want the parents to think you have bad intentions. Some parents don't mind strangers interacting with their child, others view even the smallest interaction as a prelude to molestation.

Comment: I apologise, I am someone who has taken a toddler on a 15 hour non stop flight in business class. In higher classes we are aware that our child is often the only one, and even though she has her own seat we do our absolute best to make sure she is not disruptive. I think most people with kids in premium cabins are the same.

Comment: "you won't be the grumpy gus in the next row, you'll be the toddler's airplane friend" - or you'll be the sneaky guy who first pretended to be the toddler's friend, just to figuratively stab the family in the back later on by treating a child like a device that can be switched off after a while.

Comment: There is really nothing "stab n the back" about a friendly question as to whether something different is possible or not. Also, if you've genuinely enjoyed interacting with the toddler a little, I believe your request will naturally be framed in a more friendly way. Getting along is good for everyone, as I taught a toddler or two in my time :-)

Comment: @KateGregory: Your intentions may differ, but unfortunately, first acting friendly, then suddenly asking for the kids to be "switched off", so-to-speak, does feel a lot like stabbing the family in their back. I cannot imagine a friendly way of framing that request without coming across as pretending friendliness while being mainly concerned with one's own comfort. It can come across as the stranger not wanting to get along any more, as soon as getting along starts becoming an effort for them.

Comment: It seems we can't get past "hey guys, any chance you could try a quieter form of entertainment for a little while?" being "switch that kid off instantly!" You insist that's what it means, even though I (and I have raised my children) do not mean that by it. If I want to say "shut your damn kid up and have some consideration for the rest of the plane, you're not in your living room" I will. If I say "hey guys, sorry to ask, but any chance of toning it down for 20 minutes till my headache pills take effect?" then that is what I mean, no more no less.

Comment: This is the first time I can see a benefit to noise-cancelling headphones. :-)

Comment: I find it important to mention that many (maybe a majority of) noise cancelling earphones have hard time cancelling out human voice (the good ones intentionally, I can imagine). Headphones cancelling out everything _but_ human voice can make OP's life even more miserable.

Comment: @KateGregory Great answer as always, but could I ask why first - fourth isn't capitalized :)

Comment: Great advice. Of course, it's not guaranteed to work but nothing is. I had three separate annoying kids in economy plus (recommendation 2) on my overnight flight (recommendation 1) yesterday but I agree that economy plus is usually better than ordinary economy for this.

Comment: @KateGregory: "You insist that's what it means" - no, I don't. I merely see how "hey guys, any chance you could try a quieter form of entertainment for a little while?" can be a form of stabbing the family into their back. Like it or not, the impression can be created that you didn't complain about the noise as long as *you* had your fun with the child, and once you grow tired of that activity, you expect the child to be quiet. I am not saying that is the intention, but it is what the described nehavior can come across as, and using friendlier words doesn't help solve the issue.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I'm sorry but I don't see how "wait a bit, play with the kid for a bit, wait a bit more, ask for quiet" could possibly be interpreted as "the kid's only allowed to make noise for my benefit." Sure, if it was "Get on the plane, play with the kid for a bit, 'OK, quiet now, please'" but nobody's proposing that.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: I guess my comments boil down to "A well-intentioned statement is not guaranteed to be understood as intended, especially if it's about asking others to change a behaviour."

Comment: @O.R.Mapper OK. That much I can definitely agree with, though I think Kate's taking every possible step to minimize that possibility.

Answer (score 219):

For [$160,000](http://www.privatefly.com/us/private-flights/how-much-does-a-private-flight-cost), you can hire a private jet for London - LAX return which is a similar trip length to that of London to San Francisco. This aircraft seats 13 making the trip approximately $12,300 each *if* you could find 12 other people to share it with. That's a similar price to paying for fully flexible first class.

For that you typically get a private terminal, minimal security, ability to take almost as much luggage as you wish, and an aircraft that will wait for you and take off whenever you want. You also guarantee to be sharing the aircraft with people of your choice.

The OP specifically asks "how to *avoid* toddlers". This question and similar questions, such as how do I avoid drunks, people who snore or sitting next to someone with bad body odor, or why should babies be allowed in first class, typically end up with the canonical answer that you should fly in a private jet. When you are taking a form of public transport, inevitably you are going to come across a disagreeable situation or disagreeable passengers.

On almost any airline (apart from, I think, one exception), babies and young children are allowed in all cabins including First and Business class. Children under a certain age are not allowed in the exit row, but they are allowed in front of, behind and in the bulkhead adjacent to the exit row. There are many parents who can afford to travel in Business and First and you see young children in these every day. Some parents prefer an overnight flight to a day flight in order to get the children to sleep more quickly. In summary, you can almost never be guaranteed to more than one seat away from a toddler.

If the OP had said he'd had an uncomfortable flight and asked what's the best way with dealing with noise on an aircraft, I would have provided an answer responding to that question, rather than the question that the OP did ask.

Comment: Well, the question was "how do you avoid toddllers?", which really only has one answer... If the question was how do you cope, then I'd have answered differently. ps, you can always vote it down, I won't be upset :)

Comment: Not necessarily sarcastic, and now it's 6 upvotes. I don't hire private jets, but often do hitch a ride in one. Of my three sojourns out this year, two have been charter and one has been private. So it's a very real alternative.

Comment: @GayotFow: How in the world do you do that! Does it not cost a ridiculous amount?

Comment: I don't see any sarcasm here. Since the OP is the kind of person who would use phrases like "that typical proto-speech", they will probably never be happy traveling in conveyances that they need to share with other human beings then themselves. That kind of attitude does have a (steep) monetary cost.

Comment: Families usually travel in economy class, so you can also reduce the risk by flying business or first class (or even premium economy). (This would be applying the essence of this answer on a small scale.)

Comment: Given the current cost of London -> San Francisco flights this isn't actually that ridiculous for a family

Comment: @Mehrdad it's free see http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50197/where-to-find-ferry-flights-and-empty-leg-flights

Comment: I know someone who bought a subscription for something like $10k/year and travels on as dozens of empty legs each year. No TATL yet though.

Comment: @HenningMakholm that kind of attitude has a steep cost, period.  Those who cannot afford to bear the cost monetarily bear it instead in stress and irritation.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Not idea what butthurt means, but I am a parent and I'm pretty sure none of us care what other people think of their child talking on a plane, when out shopping, in a restaurant etc.  Adults talk all the time, why should children be any different.  Just can just put in a pair of (cheap) earphones and listen to music, read etc.  A plane is full of noises, from the engines, constant announcements, other people talking etc.  It's not your personal office in the sky.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I think this is a real answer. It's not breaking any social norms (unlike the two bottom-most answers), and it's an approach that some people actually use, although for different reasons.

Comment: All the people who are automatically assuming that this answer is only liked by "angry butthurt parents" - When you grow up, and are able to procreate, you'll realize what an angry pubescent child you had to be in order to consider it okay to whine about how the continuation of your own species gets on your nerves. Once upon a time you were that annoying little kid running around blowing on your arm making fart sounds. Now you're a bigger kid crying about other kids being better behaved than you were.

Comment: @Alex Different kinds of noise are not necessarily as easily ignored as others, though. For example, two minutes after attaining level flight, I don't hear the engines - it's a nice predictable noise. But even with adults talking, it's very easy to ignore when you can hear both sides of the conversation (assuming they're not shouting at each other etc.), but almost impossible to ignore when you only hear one side (a phone call, for example) - the "broken pattern" keeps pulling you back. For some people, kiddy talk does the same thing - for others, it's barely audible music or a prayer.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire - You have no idea how things have changed with regards to expectations out of children's behavior over the last few decades or you wouldn't have written what you wrote. It wasn't that long ago where parents didn't just "wish" their children behaved but instead "made sure" their children behaved. Why do you think so many kids are now taking ADHD medication versus years ago? Hint, It isn't because more kids have ADHD.

Comment: @Dunk I am a parent and I know what you're talking about. I cringe at the number of parents I meet or hear of who use this new method of "never saying no" - Not allowed to say no to your kid at all. I sometimes wake in a cold sweat dreaming of what kind of future such a generation is going to make. That said, it sounds like this kid was doing an amazing job keeping him/her/self occupied by simply reading, and the ADULT ahead of him/her just couldn't accept that he's on a freaking plane with other people, not in his own private quarters.

Comment: @user43814 I'd argue with this. I was a quiet kid who was annoyed by other kids *even when I was a kid*. Not all kids are annoying, run around, or "blow on their arm making fart sounds", as you say. Just the *annoying* kids are like that... and there are plenty who are perfectly capable of sitting still on a plane without making a bunch of noise. To be clear: I blame the *parents* for this, not the kids. Sounds like you might be one of those parents...

Answer (score 185):

Toddlers cannot be seated in exit rows.

If you are able to select your seat, choose one that has an exit row behind it. You may lose the ability to recline your seat, but you are guaranteed that there will not be a toddler behind you.

Comment: This is the only helpful and direct answer to the question!

Comment: This sounds logical, but there tend to be a lot of toddlers in the exit row in the non-aisle area, because that's where they can put bassinets: http://www.stylehiclub.com/cruising-flying/airplane-baby-bassinet/

Comment: If you're in front of the exit row, you're not guaranteed that there's not a toddler sat next to you though.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Bassinets go in the *bulkhead* seats, which are typically not located near emergency exits.  (Although this depends on the plane model.)

Comment: On a widebody, there are often bassinet seats in the center section adjacent to the exit row seats.

Comment: Since nobody stated the obvious: If you want to be sure that there is no child behind you, book the rearmost seat.

Comment: @jpatokal look on seatguru e.g. http://www.seatguru.com/airlines/Emirates_Airlines/Emirates_Airlines_Boeing_777-300ER_3class_V2.php row

Comment: @Berwyn I think you proved my point there: only 4 of the 15 bassinets on that plane are in exit rows

Comment: @jpatokal and which exit rows don't have any bassinets?

Comment: Is there a reference or regulation that validates this fact?

Answer (score 80):

Assuming you fly with a second person, you could use a small trick to increase your level on insulation. During check-in, reserve two middle seats which are directly behind (or in front) of the exit row:

[image: seat map]

Since no children can sit in the exit row and parents will want to sit next to their children, you're guaranteed to have nine child-free seats. If you're flying with a large group you could go further and reserve a large block of middle seats around the exit row.

A similar solution could be applied to other seat configurations.

Comment: Nice idea, though I suspect if I tried this, and was the one of the two sat in row 13, someone with quintuplets would book row 14!

Comment: I know someone who has no fear to book separate seats and politely ask you to switch seats with her

Comment: @AskarKalykov You can always say no, though.

Comment: But anyway you will be sitting with a mother and a toddler in one row

Comment: Well, this conflicts with my trick of me booking the aisle and my wife booking the window, leaving the middle seat vacant-- middle seats tend to fill up last, so on non-full flights, there is a possibility of getting the whole row to ourselves. If someone does take the middle seat, they are usually willing to switch for either the window or the aisle.  We have done this with a lap infant (getting the full row on a couple of occaisions).

Comment: @pkaeding OP's problem was having a child *behind* him, not next to him.

Comment: @JonathanReez yes, but my point is that this technique is not effective in preventing families from being in rows 12 or 13, so there will not be 'nine child-free seats'.

Comment: @pkaeding if OP books the middle seat at soon as possible, families are likely to avoid booking the adjacent seats. The only truly fool-proof strategy is flying private, I'm afraid.

Comment: @JonathanReez Agreed, flying private is the only foolproof way.  Otherwise, I'd be less likely to pick that row for my family if the middle seat was already selected. My technique depends on the row being empty when I book it.

Answer (score 58):

Bring $20 - $50 cash. After you board, if you happen to be near a toddler, find a more preferable seat that seems to have a solo passenger in it, and make an attractive cash offer to the person who currently has that seat to switch with you. Be upfront with your reason for wanting to switch, as they will likely be suspicious otherwise.

Comment: This is a most reasonable suggestion. Not going to burn through your wallet unlike a first class seat or a private jet :)

Comment: Not to mention, it's only more expensive if you're unlucky. 80% of the time, you will already have an acceptable seat!

Comment: I have to say that this seems cheaper than the previous, now deleted answer involving the private jet.

Comment: Even when in steerage, it would take a lot more than $50 US to get me to switch seats to a worse one, but even $300 x 0.2 probability = $60/segment would be cheaper than a first class seat.

Comment: $50 can barely be considered "an attractive cash offer", not to mention $20.

Comment: It doesn't have to be attractive to you, just to *at least one* solo traveler. There will be low demand (just you) and high supply for this transaction, so you should have no problem finding someone happy to take another seat for <$50

Comment: Many people are far more tolerant of toddlers than say I am. There should at least one person on the plane that would enjoy having in-flight beverages and snacks on me

Comment: how am I supposed to dine on chateaubriand on 50 measly dollars?

Comment: This is a great idea. I hate bringing cash with me, but this idea makes me want to.  Sounds obvious in retrospect.  And such a bargain compared to hiring a private jet (or even paying for first class).

Comment: Agree completely: I don't mind toddlers much, as long as they're not screaming, and would absolutely *love* to be paid 50 bucks to switch seats if I were flying solo.

Answer (score 25):

Rather than using earplugs, get some headphones and listen to music or something. It'll give you something else to focus on rather than the toddler. This is the approach lots of computer programmers use in open-plan offices, by the way. If you're wanting to sleep, then choose classical music.

The following is just speculation, but it may work: try having a book, movie, or some sort of electronic device to focus on so that you aren't just thinking of, or actively trying to avoid thinking about, the toddler.

Comment: Noise-cancelling headphones playing white noise (think like the sound of an untuned radio) is another option good for sleeping.

Comment: Noise cancelling headphones playing *anything* is a good idea. As a regular flyer I can't recommend them enough (I use Bose in-ear ones as they are very lightweight but there are other options).

Comment: Noise cancelling headphones are useless for sounds that change frequently (like babies crying). They're great for flights anyway (they're good at suppressing the constant sounds of jet engines)

Comment: Agreed, in-ear earbuds and any music at all can even block out someone talking directly to you.

Comment: Yeah, there's no need for noise-canceling earphones if you have decent white noise playing that will block all sound.

Comment: I don't think you've tried sleeping to classical music when there's noise like a toddler.

Comment: @djechlin no I haven't.

Comment: classical music has the highest dynamic range. to combat noise, you need music with low dynamic range. try listening some death metal, or black metal, for example. :)

Comment: @SargeBorsch that's exactly why any type of noise, especially at 200-3kHz, is so good - the dynamic range is tiny, and setting your frequency band across the human speech band ensures you can block out humans. Headphones, now with added antisocialism :)

Comment: Active noise-cancelling headphones only work for low-ish frequency noise.  The amount of attenuation declines at higher frequencies.   My experience using them in airplanes is that they are great for cancelling out the sound of the engines but terrible at cancelling out children's voices and squeals and screams, because those are much higher pitch.   So I use passive noise-blocking earbuds (Etymotic makes some good ones) combined with a white-noise app on my phone.     I flew from Zurich to Boston last year with a screaming baby in the seat next to me and had no trouble at all.

Answer (score 17):

While long haul, no layover flights may seem advantageous, this is one area where a multi-hop flight has advantages.  If you are seated in an inconvenient manner, you don't have to deal with it the entire flight, the next flight will provide a different seating, and even if that one is inconvenient you'll at least have a layover where you can walk away from stressful environments, perhaps in lounges that cater to your need for peace and quiet.

Consider booking your next flight with multiple legs.

Comment: This is a good idea if you're not actually crossing the pacific or atlantic oceans. Flying from New Zealand to the USA, you're getting a 14hr nonstop leg across the pacific (7 if you stop in hawaii) at best. Or a trip more than three times as long (time and distance) going the other way around the world.

Answer (score 10):

You may avoid such problems if you travel first class. On the long term you may not be all that better off, as by the time you get used to traveling first class your tolerance of imperfections may decrease. See e.g. [this review](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nfkmKdyYh_Q) of Royal First Class travel on Thai Airways.

Comment: Trouble is, toddlers can travel in first class too.

Comment: @Berwyn, in First Class you get your own mini room, not completely closed off but it's still quite private.

Comment: Not in any F class from LHR-SFO though...

Comment: Fly LHR-DXB-SFO then.

Comment: In some ways it is worse if there is a crying baby in F, because the cabin is much quieter in general and the noise is much more noticeable. Especially if you are trying to finish some work before the plane lands ...

Comment: @chx For the price of Emirates First, you might as well just book a private jet...

Comment: Hardly. The DXB-SFO leg is only AED 44,305 ~12000 USD and even if you add the LHR-DXB leg you won't get above the tenth of a private jet.

Comment: The private jet seats 13 though which is $12300 each.

Comment: This is an expensive gamble.  While the likelihood is lower, I can speak from personal experience that young children are perfectly welcome in first class.  The advantage though is the kids tend to be more well behaved than in coach.

Answer (score 6):

Judging from your description it seems like your complaints are mainly noise related. You would most likely benefit from some noise canceling headphones. While there are many models out there, [Bose](http://www.innerfidelity.com/content/better-travelers-sanctuary-bose-quiet-comfort-25#yc0K2beu7FeoJSwG.97) has a pretty good reputation in this area.

Comment: Noise cancelling technology in headphones (Active noise control (ANC)) will not diminish the sound of a person talking, or a child reading.  This technology can only "cancel out" noise by emitting a sound wave with the same amplitude but with inverted phase.  So, given enough of a sample (over time) it can detect and match persistent noise at fixed frequencies (e.g. Aeroplane engines, fans, etc) but it cannot adapt fast enough to cancel out the variable tones of human speech.

Answer (score 6):

White noise is particularly good at "cushioning" sound so that the highs/lows as well as ambient sounds blend into the background.

In fact, there are [very well-reviewed machines](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000KUHFGM) whose sole purpose is to make white noise to help block out sound and make it easier to fall asleep.

For situations like yours, though, I usually just go to iTunes and play a white noise song on loop, to help me focus and block out distracting noise, whether it be at work, home, or while traveling.

My song of choice is "[Ocean Waves](https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/help-your-baby-sleep-through/id292705464)" but there's a wide variety of white noise songs to pick from, depending on your preference.

Comment: "white noise songs" is nonsense. white noise is a clearly defined thing, and it cannot be in any way different from itself, besides the loudness level at which it's played

Comment: Mm, I must be using the wrong jargon then. At any case, any noise that sounds similar to white noise should suffice.

Comment: I personally find [white noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:White-noise-sound-20sec-mono-44100Hz.ogg) to be somewhat eardrum piercing. [Pink noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Pink_noise.ogg), [brown noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Brownnoise.ogg) and [grey noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Gray_noise.ogg) are all much softer.

Comment: Definitely digging the Brownian noise--it's feels smooth and soft, like running water.