# Do any airlines have bans on children from certain passenger sections?

Tags: airlines, children, discrimination

Do any airlines have bans on children riding in certain passenger sections? (As opposed to banning them from the cockpit)

I think I've heard about it before, but possibly as something proposed and then rejected, rather than being implemented.

[Four "no-kids zone" airlines putting business travellers first](http://www.ausbt.com.au/four-no-kids-zone-airlines-putting-business-travellers-first) claims four airlines are doing it.

Comment: +1 I would be very interested in knowing what they are, so I can boycott them.

Comment: @fkraiem Boycott?! This is first/business class only we're taking about here, do you also object to luxury resorts that don't allow children?

Comment: None of the majors I fly with have any bans on children in certain cabins.  My three year old has flown Thai in Royal Silk (business) with me before without issue (though I haven't flown their A380 yet).

Comment: @jpatokal at first I assumed children would be only banned from first/business class, but the linked article said that MAS upstairs economy is also banning them (though same principle, as I assume "upstairs" = "premium").

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69053/how-to-avoid-toddlers-on-a-long-distance-plane-flight

Comment: First class on airlines is kind of like Monaco .. surprisingly, lots of small children.  I wonder if the actual percentage of children in 1st class is higher than in economy?  Rich people have, and can afford children, and take the children with them around the world.  I'm not sure if you realize, the linked article, which is flakey, is very old.  I would be surprised to learn that any airlines ban kids in first or business; I couldn't really find any clear up to date articles.  (There seems to be some weird Australian thing - if you google the topic, Australia keeps coming up.)

Comment: Andrew, *"the linked article said that MAS upstairs economy is also banning them"*  Actually the very old linked article (which is incredibly flakey, even more flakey than the first article!) says precisely and exactly that someone at MAS thought about "banning kids upstairs" but then they explicitly realized they would never be able to do this.  You know, googling around I'm pretty sure in actual answer to your question there are **no, zero** airlines which ban kids in 1st: I'm surprised, I figured at least one would be trying it a given time you know?

Comment: I can confirm Air Asia X has this under their "Quite zone" add-on (about $10-20 extra). But it is merely for the babies (not young children). It's basically the same economy class, with a partitioned space. It is located at the front of the aircraft, and it is really relatively quite.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb airlines do not ban children from any level of service, they will sell tickets to anyone with the cash.  My daughter has flown in business class on several airlines without issue and I have seen plenty of kids in business and first class on all the airlines I fly.

There are likely some destinations served where cultures keep children separate from adults or relegated to a lower status. On routes serving these destinations, some airlines may try to keep children out of the upper class, to keep the local business travelers who frequent the route happy.

And I know some airlines have tried to introduce quiet zones, by banning kids, but boisterous, non-stop talking adults are just as bothersome as the kid who cries occasionally.

Comment: _"boisterous, non-stop talking adults are just as bothersome as the kid who cries occasionally."_ +1 for this.

Answer (score 5):

The only place children (and minors) cannot be seated is in the exit row. The same goes for anyone physically unable to operate the emergency equipment / exit doors; or is otherwise incapable (for example, there is a language barrier).

Other than that, children are allowed on all sections of the aircraft where passengers are allowed. I have personally been on a flight with toddlers and infants in business class.

The link you have posted is just a marketing thing; just like some airlines fly business-only flights to certain destinations.