# Are there any child-free flight options?

Tags: air-travel, children

I was wondering whether there are any flights for people who can't stand children or don't want to be around them. I'm sure there is a demand. By child-free, I mean child-free flights, child-free zones, or other options. Can I request a child-free option on a regular flight to have no kids sitting nearby? How much does it cost to have a child-free flight compared to a normal one?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80306/discussion-on-question-by-fixerlt-are-there-any-child-free-flight-options).

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/70736/

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69053/how-to-avoid-toddlers-on-a-long-distance-plane-flight?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: You can always chart a fly entirely to you and invite only the people you stand (and people stand being with you)

Comment: If you fly first class, you'll get your own private cabin.

Comment: First Class. Business Class. But for the rest of us: noise cancelling headphones.

Comment: @NigelTouch is Business Class child-free?

Comment: @hanshenrik sadly not. Some people with no idea of public behaviour bring children there.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

So far as I can tell, there are no commercial flights that are entirely child-free, There are unlikely to be, as the economics of commercial aviation work against it—the flying public favors low fares over essentially all other considerations. Every few years there is a [new column](https://www.nytimes.com/2010/11/14/travel/14babies-journeys.html) suggesting it, but in the end, people aren't really willing to pay what it would take to support a child-free flight network.

From 1953 to 1970, United Airlines [in]famously offered so-called [Executive flights](https://viewfromthewing.boardingarea.com/2015/05/27/united-airlines-men-only-executive-service/) that were for men only, between New York and Chicago and between Los Angeles and San Francisco. Cigar and pipe smoking were allowed, women and children were not. That was probably the last of it for entirely child-free flights, certainly from any U.S. carrier.

There are, however, a number of airlines that have "child-free zones" on selected flights. Malaysian Airlines was the first in recent years, banning children from the upper deck on its A380s. Scoot offers a [ScootinSilence](https://www.flyscoot.com/en/fly-scoot/onboard/economy-class) upgrade for economy; no one under the age of 12 may be seated in the front of their 787 cabins. AirAsia X, the long-haul sister airline of AirAsia, offers what they call a [Quiet Zone](https://support.airasia.com/s/article/AirAsia-X-Quiet-Zone?language=en_GB):

> **1. What is Quiet Zone?**
>   - Quiet Zone is an exclusive seating area between rows 7-14.
>   - Only available to guest who is aged 10 years and above.

Speaking as someone without children who flies a lot, I think it's a silly marketing ploy; I encounter far, far more annoying adults than annoying children on any given trip. Besides, it isn't as if there is a soundproof barrier around those sections. [IndiGo offers child-free seating](http://www.latimes.com/business/la-fi-travel-briefcase-child-free-20161022-snap-story.html) in rows 1–4 and 11–14, but sitting in row 4 won't insulate you from a fussy toddler in row 5.

Whether the option will spread outside of Southeast and South Asia remains to be seen. Even though *The Independent* declared it a "[growing movement](https://www.independent.co.uk/travel/news-and-advice/air-travel-child-free-zones-planes-movement-cabin-crew-noise-crying-a8217191.html)," there have been no new announcements since IndiGo announced it in 2016.

Comment: Thank you for providing a well-informated answer. I'd like to add that i flight about dozen times and i've never experienced an annoying adult, but there were several annoying children. Probably, you deal with children better than i do.

Comment: +1 for "I encounter far, far more annoying adults than annoying children on any given trip"

Comment: I rarely encounter many people at all whilst flying, but when there are consistently annoying ones, they do tend to be infants or toddlers. Being sat next to a colicky or teething baby who screams pretty much incessantly all the way from London to Los Angeles is, I can inform you, not a joy. I have come across adults who exhibited annoying behaviour or bad manners, but those rarely last more than a few minutes. The annoying adults may outnumber the infants in absolute numbers, but the infants quite consistently outscream the annoying adults.

Comment: Judging from your first paragraph, I'm not part of the flying public as I favor midday flights over early morning flights even if they are a bit more expensive :) . But I come to the same conclusion: I assume only a small part of all flights could be child-free, and I can imagine a lot of reasons for people not to pick that flight (more expensive, bad travel times, no miles for a flight on this airline, ...)

Comment: @Sabine But given two midday flights with comparable schedules, how much of a premium are you (or your employer) willing to pay? My last employer allowed me to book a flight on the airline of my choice if it was less than 10% over the cheapest fare. That wasn't enough to save, say, "full service" pre-2002 USAir from "low cost" Southwest, even though the USAir hub at BWI would have served the company's interests far better in the long run. Southwest is a very fine airline, but it doesn't serve nearly as many small cities, for example.

Comment: Sitting in row four won’t insulate you from a screaming toddler in row _twenty_.

Comment: I've been on commercial flights that were free of children, but that was by chance rather than design. Flying outside of school holidays, during periods and between city pairs mostly frequented by business travelers, on mainline carriers, tends to increase those chances. But no guarantee of course.

Comment: @WGroleau: I am glad I was not the only one thinking this. I still remember a flight a few years back with a toddler ~20 rows behind me screaming/crying the whole time. The poor little thing may have had ear issues, from what I understood, and despite both parents and hostesses attention only calmed down after landing. On the other hand, the Malaysian Airlines strategy of having a child-free deck seems like it could provide sufficient isolation.

Comment: On BA, probably a 777 of some sort, premium economy was separated from proper economy  by a galley or toilets and curtains, and had few or no (detectable) kids.  This helped a lot on an overnight flight as did the slightly reduced density of adults

Comment: I would add that while first class is not exclusively for adults, you don't often find children in these more expensive seats. Plus, there's often a good amount of separation between first class and the economy seats.

Comment: I find the concept of "quiet zone" close to several turbines revolving at a high speed to be interesting.

Comment: "encounter far, far more annoying adults than annoying children on any given trip." But would you encounter them on a flight full of adults *trying* to avoid annoying children?

Comment: @Joshua To be frank, the chances would slightly increase in such a specific population, yes.

Comment: I could pay up to 50% more of my flight ticket to be sure I won't be disturbed by screaming children. Especially during medium and long flights (more than 2 hrs).
@Davidmh the turbine's noise is deep and regular, which is totally different from high-pitched screaming young voice.

Comment: @AlexB Sure, *you* might, or you might adjust your schedule to book the one flight a day that offers such an amenity to your destination. And others would happily do so for business class legroom (that's still cheaper than actual business class after all) and so forth. But *most* will not, and the economy cabin only contributes to the bottom line if you keep service and prices as close to the lowest common denominator as possible.

Comment: @Davidmh The sound of the engines is consistent, though, which generally makes it easier for your brain to tune it out entirely. (If it isn't consistent, you may have larger concerns than noise.) A crying baby, somebody with an annoying laugh, etc. are much harder to ignore if you can hear them.

Comment: You obviously don't fly much. Children are, on average, much much worse copassengers than adults.

Answer (score 19):

Children and infants are not allowed in the emergency exit rows of airplanes. However, it only provides a guarantee that a child won’t sit next (laterally) to you — one might still be behind or ahead of you in a non-exit row. If you can find a plane where the exit rows correspond with a change in class or there are multiple exit rows, you might be able to build more of a buffer.  I often use [seatguru](https://www.seatguru.com) to find the row directly ahead of the exit row because there will be no children behind me - or the row behind the exit row if I need to do work on my laptop, because exit row seats are not capable of reclining.

In addition personally, I find that earplugs or a good set of noise cancelling headphones along with good music or a movie of my choice more than drowns out the world. If you’re really bothered, in-ear earplugs combined with over the ear noise cancelling headsets (or in-ear noise cancelling headphones combined with over the ear ear protection) will give you around 40dB of noise reduction - more than needed for most children.

Finally, parents of small children often can’t afford to fly business or first class. There’s also greater seat separation and/or privacy partitioning in those classes. You may find that one way that airlines offer a “choice” (albeit expensive one) to business travelers who absolutely need to get some sleep or work done.

Comment: Even without trying to avoid hearing other passengers, I’ve found earplugs to be invaluable as a frequent traveler — I’m way less exhausted after a flight if I’m not hearing several hours straight of 500 MPH wind rushing past the plane. You don’t really realize how loud the baseline level of noise is in a jet airliner until you take earplugs _out_ mid-flight.

Comment: Sadly, I don't think noise-cancelling technology has yet evolved to cancel the toddler in the seat behind who kicks you in the back for an hour ;-)

Comment: The in-ear and larger over-the-ear noise cancelling headphones have considerable physical sound attenuation. So they’ll knock a few decibels off even the gutsiest child. Good in-ears combined with over the ear ear protection renders the entire world silent.

Comment: @Flyto If someone kicks you for an hour, it's your own fault by not trying to get them to stop.

Comment: @AzorAhai I think that's somewhat true, but it dismisses the fact that someone kicking you for an hour is rude. They are the one truly at fault here.

Comment: @ell I never said they weren't be rude, but I meant, there's at least three people you can talk to get it to stop: the kid, the guardian, and the flight attendant. If someone kicks you for a whole hour, that means you didn't even try to get them to stop.

Comment: Counterpoint but not a contradiction: the most well-behaved my toddler has ever been on a flight was when we got a first-class upgrade together. Turns out the little ones like space as much as grown-ups. She was too young to notice the stink-eye she got from the guy who missed the upgrade cutoff.

Comment: @AzorAhai the key word there is "try" ;-)

Comment: @ell Toddlers move around a lot and do not have well developed motor skills. If one is bumping on the back of your seat, realize that they are certainly not considering your existence or what effect touching the solid permanent barrier in front of them will have on *you*. If you are bothered try mentioning it to the parents right away instead of when you are hopelessly angry, steeping in toxic bitter feelings. Parents have a lot of experience keeping their children from doing annoying things. If they do nothing or blow you off, the **PARENTS** are rude, and it is their fault.

Answer (score 12):

Your only real option is to charter your very own aircraft and crew (unless you're a pilot yourself of course, in which case you might be able to rent an aircraft and fly it yourself if your ratings allow you to fly an aircraft with sufficient range and passenger capacity for your purpose).

The cost of that is pretty steep, several hundred to many thousands of dollars PER HOUR just for the aircraft, not taking into consideration payment for the crew, fuel, landing fees, etc. etc.

It's a great way to travel, but it's expensive.
Maybe some day I'll be allowed and able to have my own aircraft, but for now I'm just a student pilot learning the ropes.

Comment: With respect, whilst the ground experience (turn up and go) is a blessed relief over large passenger terminals, the in-flight experience tends to be nothing like the “great way to travel” offered by a (far less expensive) premium cabin on a scheduled carrier.  Give me First on an A380 with a fully flat bed, cocktail bar, food cooked to order and a hot shower over a cronky Learjet with seats that don’t fully recline, a mediocre galley with only cold food and a loo that flushes by manual pumping any day.

Comment: @eggyal personal preference. I enjoy the experience of controlling an aircraft. And you should compare that first class seat on Emirates with a brand new G650, not a 40 year old Learjet.

Answer (score 9):

I don't know about kids of age, but when I was flying with infant I have noticed that places for parents with infant are all in the forward section. So you can try choosing seats in the back. This was just one airline though, so your mileage may vary.

Come to think of it, back section is often considered undesirable, so you could choose seats in the back to minimize the absolute number of neighbours around you - provided that flight isn't packed.

Then again, by choosing flights which are rarely full (this probably means more expensive airlines on less popular routes), and there choosing undesirable seats, you could minimize the amount of kids around you.

Comment: Right now you are offering me to choose unpleasant flights: overpriced, bad timings, etc. and/or choose unpleasant seats in flight to avoid a certain group of passanges that is not a solution nohow, since i want to increase my comfort during the flight and by doing what u propose my comfort will be decreased.

Comment: @fixerlt Yes; basically, you can trade one comfort for another.

Comment: The fixtures for attaching [baby bassinets](https://www.flyingwithababy.com/essential-airline-bassinet-information-chart/) are generated located in bulkhead rows in the economy cabin, and on most narrowbody planes, this is also the first row of economy, which is why you perceive that they are seated towards the front. But bassinets can only accommodate very young infants and are often fitted only on longer flights, so I would not say choosing a seat in the back to avoid babies is workable even as a rule of thumb.

Comment: @alamar the purpose of the question is about trading money(maybe time) to comfort

Comment: @fixerlt actually, flights which are half empty are much more comfortable, so if you can find those, you will not be disappointed.

Answer (score 6):

In my experience over 30 years of air travel, the only solution I have discovered to simulate a child-free flight is to plug in and turn on my Bose noise *reducing* headphones.  It's not perfect, but if you crank up your favorite music, the headphones can lull you into a Thoreauly Walden-Pond state of solitude.  It is also effective for ignoring your rude adult row mates.

Comment: yeah. I've a set of Philips ones myself. Work great to cut out the drone of the engines as well.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I request a child-free option on a regular flight to have no kids
>   sitting nearby?

Perhaps not from the airline, but you could always see if other passengers in seats you feel are more optimal are willing to switch.

Personally, I love kids, even before having my own I've always loved the energy and raw emotion they show. I also love parents, doing the best they can to bring up their young ones when they really have no idea what they are doing.

With this in mind, sitting next to screaming kids on a plane has never bothered me. If I'm feeling social, and the parent welcomes it, I'll easily try and help out stop the screaming by just pulling funny faces, playing peekaboo, lending them my tablet and that sort of stuff. If I don't feel social I'll fall asleep or put in my head phones and ignore it.

> the purpose of the question is about trading money (maybe time) to
>   comfort – fixerIt (comment)

Then you are in luck, because as well as loving kids and parents I also love money. Even if I'm not feeling social and don't want to switch seats the added incentive of some money for doing so would almost guarantee it.

> How much does it cost to have a child-free flight compared to a normal
>   one?

£50 would guarantee it from me but other passengers may do it for less. You could always haggle as well, depending on my mood I'd probably go as low as £20.

---

Of course some people may take umbrage at you trying to get out of sitting next to a screaming child and think you a bit conceited for doing so and suggesting they should sit there instead. To try avoid hurt feelings as soon as you ask I'd suggest leading with a plausible reason as to why you want to switch (even if it is a white lie). Something like '*I've a meeting as soon as I get off the flight and could really do with getting some rest.*' rather than just '*I don't like kids.*'

Something that makes the person you want to switch with feel like they are helping you out will make them more likely to help.

Comment: Is it the screaming or the soiled diapers and no lavatories available or parents not noticing their child needs changing or passengers not being allowed to leave their seats causing one to sit in a miasma of foul odor for long periods of time? There's earplugs for the screaming, but nose plugs are not widely available.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I have to admit (and this is mostly since becoming a parent), there is a certain satisfaction from having a baby next to you with the most foul smelling nappy in the world and knowing that, even though you are having to endure it just now, you aren't the one who is going to have to open it up, view it, inhale it _unfiltered_ and change it! I wouldn't say I actively seek them out though :D.

Comment: I am pretty certain that the airline maintains that the seats are non transferable.  In general, they are not apt to care if you sit in my seat and I in your ... if we are both happy sitting in the wrong seat, why would the airline care.  However, if the airline saw significant money change hands they might try get their hands on that money.  "Sirs:  go back to your assigned seats.  If you want to change seats, you both need to pay an upgrade fee."

Comment: @emory, Not sure if you are joking or not so going to respond as if you were serious. I think most airlines don't care about you changing seat once in flight so long as other rules are adhered to (seat belts, ticket class and so on) so I don't think this counts as 'transferable' (note as well that it is technically the ticket that is non-transferable, not the seat). And I think it would have to happen *a lot* before airlines decided to charge an in-flight transfer fee! Any stewards that try it off their own back would likely be risking their jobs. So yeah, I hope your comment was in jest. :)

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland I agree airlines mostly don't care, but if it became common or if there was a lot of money involved that could change.  If you are willing to "spend whatever it takes to force the swap on something who is not basically agreeable" then you might have to pay the airline off as well.

Answer (score -4):

Your last ditch software solution is to try to use [SeatSwap](http://www.getseatswap.com/) **after you've boarded the plane** to move seats to a different part of the plane farther from the most troublesome children.  Not the best solution, but it's still an option!

I am not affiliated with the site in any way whatsoever. I saw this post in the sidebar while reading an iOS post, and I realized that I had seen the seatswap app advertised a few months back and thought the OP might be interested to know.

Comment: Can you please include what the site behind the link is about and can you please disclose whether you are connected to that site?

Comment: I notice that the site has an invalid certificate when you try to search.

Comment: I am not affiliated with the site in any way whatsoever.  I saw this post in the sidebar while reading an iOS post, and I realized that I had seen the seatswap app advertised a few months back and thought the OP might be interested to know.  I’m a seasoned Stack user, and this is by far the worst thing about this platform- it is assumed post responders are idiots or spammers.  Don’t perpetuate the crappiness.  Ugh.

Comment: The answer makes no sense. How would you know in advance that your seat is near a child?

Comment: You can use this app *when you're on the flight*.  I didn't say anything about doing this in advance.